# Fill percentage of JTextArea background

Tags: java, swing

I'm attempting to partially fill a JTextArea based on an object's member field that is between 0 and 1.  If I hard code the percentage in the paintComponent function, it works great.  But when I try to use the member field as the percentage value, it's always 0.0 in the debugger and no rectangle is painted behind the text.

Why are the member fields seemingly uninitialized within `paintComponent()`?  After calling `setPercent()`, `percentFilled` is correct. (I do invalidate the container of the `BarGraphText` objects after their `setPercent()` are called.)

**EDIT:** `setPercent()` is called after an ActionListener is triggered by a button.  Would the separate gui thread have something to do with this failing?  It works when the class below is in a JFrame by itself. **Update:** Having a button change the percent and redraw the component makes no difference when I have this in a separate project.

**Solved:** I was clearing the values at the wrong spot in my program.  I'll leave this question published.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;


public class BarGraphText extends JTextArea {
double percentFilled;
Color fillColor;

BarGraphText( String s )
{
    super(s);
    setOpaque(false);

    percentFilled = 0.0;
}

@Override
public void paintComponent( Graphics g )
{
    int width, height;
    Rectangle bounds = g.getClipBounds();

    if( bounds != null )
    {
        height = bounds.height;
        width = bounds.width;
    }
    else
    {
        System.err.println("Error [BarGraphText]: Clipping bounds unknown.");
        height = width = 0;
    }

    g.setColor(fillColor);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, (int) (width*percentFilled), height);

    super.paintComponent(g);
}

public void setPercent( int myResp, int totResp )
{
    percentFilled = (float)myResp / totResp;
}

public void setColor( Color c )
{
    fillColor = c;
}
}
```

Comment: Although you are casting a `float` to a `double`, your code works for me. Provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for better help

Comment: Also works for me when I isolate it...I'll keep ya'll up to date

Comment: Been about 18 days since this saw an update - vlad, can you close it out if your question has been answered?

Comment: Close it out?  The last edit said it's solved, is that not sufficient..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was clearing the values at the wrong spot in my program.  This is not in the code published above.